# emacs auto-complete-clang-async not working

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete

I compiled the *clang-complete* and put it in ~/.emacs.d/ .
My *init.el* configures the plugin as follows:

```
(require 'auto-complete-clang-async)

 (defun ac-cc-mode-setup ()
  (setq ac-clang-complete-executable "~/.emacs.d/clang-complete")
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-clang-async))
  (ac-clang-launch-completion-process))

(defun ac-common-setup ()())

(defun my-ac-config ()
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ac-cc-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t) 
  (setq ac-auto-show-menu 1))

(setq ac-clang-flags
      (mapcar (lambda (item)(concat "-I" item))
              (split-string
               "
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
"
               )))

(my-ac-config)
```

I had to define an empty *ac-common-setup* function as auto complete didn't find it.
When I open a cpp file it states on the bottom right:

```
(C++/l AC yas...)
```

I don't get any error but auto completion doesn't work for c++.

Comment: "I had to define an empty ac-common-setup function as auto complete didn't find it." <- that seems like a big red flag, is autocomplete working at all in other modes like emacs-lisp?

Comment: emacs-lisp is working like a charm. It also sounds weird to me but the  original auto-complete-clang plugin commented it out in the example config. I spotted out that the compiled _clang-complete_ could be the problem. If I try to start it from the command line I get the following error: `./clang-complete: error while loading shared libraries: libclang.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Objective: Indeed, that is a **huge** red flag :)  Is your clang/llvm in a nonstandard location?  If so, you might need to check/change `process-environment` for shell env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: No i did not change anything. I build the llvm from source now and added it to the path but it is still not working.

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is that clang-complete executable can't find shared library, but I have libclang1 and libclang-dev installed